# custom wait processor creating too much log

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created a custom log processor. which i use to put a wait by using "Penalty duration".

following is my code to achieve this. Processor works as expected.but when it runs, i can see lots of logs getting generated. i can see logs keeps printing "**flow file is null (bad)!!!**". simple solution would be to comment out log, but still processor is getting called so many time. I always though, if i increase **yield** value, processor gets called in that much interval.

so my question is, how to press less pressure on CPU and reduce number of time onTrigger method gets called.

```
@Override
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
    final ComponentLog logger = getLogger();
    FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
    if (flowFile != null) {
        logger.info("flow file is not null.");
        String state = flowFile.getAttribute("_wait_state");
        if (state == null || state.isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("\"_wait_state\" attribute is missing, going into WAIT.");
            flowFile = session.putAttribute( flowFile, "_wait_state", "1");
            flowFile = session.penalize(flowFile);
            context.yield();//to save CPU cycles....
            session.transfer( flowFile, POINT_TO_SELF_RELATIONSHIP );
        } else {
            logger.info("\"_wait_state\" attribute is available, breaking WAIT.");
            flowFile = session.removeAttribute( flowFile, "_wait_state" );
            session.transfer( flowFile, SUCCESS_RELATIONSHIP); 
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("flow file is null (bad)!!!.");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `null` flow file is ok - so just remove this logging. to manage number/time triggering use scheduling processor parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal for a processor to get a null flow file, it can happen for two reasons...

1) The processor has more than one concurrent task configured, and the framework detects there is a flow file in the incoming queue, so schedules the processor to run, then one of the tasks gets the flow file and the other goes to execute and there are no flow files left.

2) The processor has the @TriggerWhenEmpty annotation which overrides the above behavior and executes the processor all the time regardless of whether flow files are in the queue.

Most processors start their onTrigger with something like:

```
FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile == null) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: sounds like a plan.